# Using WideCharToMultiByte

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to transfer and show an string from a control in VC++ to a file.
in this way, I use the `WideCharToMultiByte()` function. But there is a problem!

This is my code:

```cpp
CString m_sName=L"ABC";
int size_needed=WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
std::string utf8_string(size_needed, 0);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, &utf8_string[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);

FILE *file;
fopen_s(&file, "bid.txt", "wb");
fprintf(file, "\nutf8_string[0]=%c", utf8_string[0]);
fprintf(file, "\nutf8_string[1]=%c", utf8_string[1]);
fprintf(file, "\nutf8_string[2]=%c", utf8_string[2]);
fprintf(file, "\nutf8_string=%s", utf8_string);
fclose(file);
```

When I open the `bid.txt` file, I can see:

```
utf8_string[0]=A
utf8_string[1]=B
utf8_string[2]=C
```

but:

`utf8_string=NULL` instead of `utf8_string=ABC`

this is my problem. WHY?!!

Comment: `fprintf` doesn't know how to print a `std::string`. You could use `utf8_string.c_str()`.

Comment: Generally, make sure you include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Didn't you get a compiler warning?  I suggest setting `/W3` (IIRC, `/W4` generates a lot of noise from Microsoft's own header files, but it's worth trying).

Comment: you need `fprintf(file, "\nutf8_string=%s", utf8_string.c_str())`